# Prevent httpClient from initiating new calls

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpclient

I want to load a webpage using httpclient and GetAsync() method. This webpage makes some ajax calls or loads some javascript to fill some part of webpage that i don't need them. Is there any way to tell httpclient to just loads the plain part of html (as it is sent by server) and stops loading javascripts or images or any other thing?

Comment: HttpClient doesn't execute any javascript code, or any other client or server-side scripts. WebBrowsers do.

Comment: For me, it sounds that it takes more than necessary. I was thinking it may loads other parts of page, though not executing them. I checked the size of GetAsync()'s result with Chrome developer tools and it sounds it is my mistake. Thanks anyway.